# How to change dynamic ImageButton's image on hover?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to change dynamic `ImageButton`'s image on hover.

Here are my attempts to realize it:

```
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton { ImageUrl = "~/images/1.png", CssClass = "changeImage" };
```

And on CSS I tried several variants:

```
imageButton.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "this.className='overbutton'"); 

.changeImage { 
     background: Url("~/images/1.png"); 
} 

.overbutton { 
     background: Url("~/images/2.png"); 
}
```

Second attempt:

```
imageButton.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "Url(~/images/2.png))");
```

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Excuse me please. I could not change with editing  because there was some error.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Button

```
 ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton { CssClass = "changeImage" };
```

Add Css :

```
 .changeImage {
        background: Url("images/1.png");
    }

 .changeImage:hover {
        background: Url("images/2.png");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an ImageButton. The image is set as `src`, not as background. So either use a normal Button or change the image with jquery.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/1.jpg" CssClass="changeImage" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.changeImage').bind('mouseover', function (e) {
            $(this).prop('src', '/2.jpg');
        });
        $('.changeImage').bind('mouseout', function (e) {
            $(this).prop('src', '/1.jpg');
        });
    });
</script>
```

To use a normal button

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="changeImage" />

<style>
    .changeImage {
        background-image: url('/1.jpg');
    }

    .changeImage:hover {
        background-image: url('/2.jpg');
    }
</style>
```